# Queueable HttpCallout.TooManyCalloutsException: Too many callouts requested vs SFDC Limit: 0

Tags: callout, limits, queueable

I have a Queueable class that performs a single callout. When it executes, it generates this error:

> HttpCallout.TooManyCalloutsException: Too many callouts requested vs SFDC Limit: 0

```apex
public class MyQueueable implements System.Queueable{
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
        system.debug('callout limits='+ Limits.getLimitCallouts()); // <= displays 0
        
        ... do a callout here
    }
}
```

- How can the SFDC callout limit be zero?
- Where is this documented?
- How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Posting this as Q&A because if you actually Google (as of this writing):*

```
"HttpCallout.TooManyCalloutsException: Too many callouts requested vs SFDC Limit: 0"
```

you don't get any matches.

- The [Apex Developer Guide on Queueable Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm?q=Queueable) is silent on this subject
- The [Apex Developer Guide on Callout Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm?q=callout) is silent as well
- Various StackExchange and other posts that show examples of Queueables *might* hint at the solution but only if you know where to look
- The [Apex Developer Guide on Schedulable Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm?q=Database.AllowsCallouts) has an oblique reference that is relevant but only if you make the mental leap from how Batchables can do callouts (and, if you've never written a Batchable, you might not be aware of this):

> Synchronous Web service callouts are not supported from scheduled Apex. To make asynchronous callouts, use Queueable Apex, implementing the Database.AllowsCallouts marker interface.

The solution is to add `Database.AllowsCallouts` to your `Queueable` class definition

```
public class MyQueueable implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

  public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
    system.debug('callout limits='+ Limits.getLimitCallouts()); // <= displays 100
    
    ... do a callout here
  }

}
```

Note that if an outer class `implements Database.AllowsCallouts`, this is not inherited by any inner class that implements `System.Queueable`

Comment: The clue is definitely in the limit of 0... but you are right, this requires some experience to understand.